# why do I get uninitialized constant Devise name Error when running webrick server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

In my application I have used ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0.3 and have also installed Devise gem.The problem begins when I run the Webrick server I get uninitialized constant Devise name Error.

```
       /home/app/Workspace/project/Library_Management/Library_Management/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /home/app/Workspace/project/Library_Management/Library_Management/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/app/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/app/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /home/app/Workspace/project/Library_Management/Library_Management/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
from /home/app/Workspace/project/Library_Management/Library_Management/config.ru:1:in `new'
from /home/app/Workspace/project/Library_Management/Library_Management/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:253:in `wrapped_app'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rack-1.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:204:in `start'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
from /home/app/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/app/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `require'
from /home/app/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:58:in `rescue in require'
from /home/app/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
```

Thanks

Comment: is Devise in your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: I got the type of error, and for me it actually helped to close the terminal and open a new one. Might be helpfull, but I'm not going to post this as an answer because I do not know what caused this.

Comment: Make sure to restart your server after you install a new gem.

Answer (score 19):

Check your config/application.rb, you need to add require 'devise' and you should be fine.

Answer (score 18):

In case you are writing an engine which has its own devise config, just add

```
require 'devise'
```

on the beginning of devise initializer.
In my case I had no devise requirement within application :)

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you've listed Devise in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Comment: yes i have listed devise n also ran bundle install but still i am getting the same error..

Comment: Inside the Configuration/application.rb i added the line require 'devise' and was able to fix the problem

Comment: Also, try "bundle update" as it will be a bit more aggressive in installing updates. It updates all gems with all dependencies which often can help ironing out bugs like this. HAve a look at http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/

Comment: I am still having this same problem- strangely however only in my development environment.  I just need to restart my development server and that clears it.  But after one user login attempt it blows up again.  I tried the includes as listed above but they seem like they should not be needed -and they don't help for me.

Answer (score 3):

I got an error like that when I had a custom devise controller to override the 'new' method to do some custom stuff, and forgot to use 'super'

Do you have a custom controller?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and i found this https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

It says you have to do

`rails generate devise:install`

Following "Getting Started" on that page got me going

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using devise gem anymore then remove

```
gem 'devise'
```

from gemfile and delete

```
config/initializers/devise.rb
```

also make sure devise is not being used anywhere

Answer (score 1):

I just had that issue, it was because I generated a view model by mistake and I didnt delete it from my routes.rb

Answer (score 1):

I had to add `require 'devise'` in the spec/spec_helper.rb file and that error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I added few columns after I install Devise and I added some validations in my user model.
From error message, it looks like rails cannot find the essential library therefore it can't find Devise. Maybe checkout the Github devise Wiki page and makes sure all the dependencies are satisfied?

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

**In your config/application.rb add `require 'yaml'`. It works for me. Try**