# Application error when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

So I've spent about a week on a new app, and have just been hit with a low-blow, I seem to be getting an application error when deploying to Heroku. I've sent a message into Heroku tech support but they seem to be back-logged.

There are clearly errors in the log, however I am not sure how to troubleshoot them as I am quite new to rails.

#### Update1: rorra's new gemfile contents helped fix the initial error! (my gemfile wasn't properly formatted)

#### Update2: now getting the following message: We're sorry, but something went wrong.

```
New Heroku logs:


[StartupBlog]$heroku logs
2013-03-01T00:41:47+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-03-01T00:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-03-01 00:41:48 +0000
2013-03-01T00:41:48+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (336.9ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (302.2ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 671ms
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (logo.png isn't precompiled):
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="navbar-inner">
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <a class="brand"><%=link_to logo, root_path %></a>
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <ul class="nav pull-right">
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:       <li class="home"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:       <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `logo'
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/partials/_header.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_partials__header_html_erb___985491214305097811_33520600'
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__2767656240117324842_33999760'
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:49+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=6ms service=1730ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-03-01 00:41:52 +0000
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (7.0ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (logo.png isn't precompiled):
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="navbar-inner">
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <a class="brand"><%=link_to logo, root_path %></a>
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `logo'
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/partials/_header.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_partials__header_html_erb___985491214305097811_33520600'
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__2767656240117324842_33999760'
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:       <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <ul class="nav pull-right">
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:       <li class="home"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:52+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=6ms connect=27ms service=119ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-03-01 00:41:55 +0000
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (logo.png isn't precompiled):
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="navbar-inner">
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <a class="brand"><%=link_to logo, root_path %></a>
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:       <li class="home"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <ul class="nav pull-right">
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:       <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `logo'
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/partials/_header.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_partials__header_html_erb___985491214305097811_33520600'
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__2767656240117324842_33999760'
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:55+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=5ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-03-01 00:41:59 +0000
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.9ms)
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms connect=2ms service=20ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (logo.png isn't precompiled):
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="navbar-inner">
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <a class="brand"><%=link_to logo, root_path %></a>
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:       <li class="home"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:       <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/partials/_header.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_partials__header_html_erb___985491214305097811_33520600'
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__2767656240117324842_33999760'
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `logo'
2013-03-01T00:41:59+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <ul class="nav pull-right">
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 174.95.207.136 at 2013-03-01 00:42:22 +0000
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.3ms)
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:       <li class="home"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/partials/_header.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_partials__header_html_erb___985491214305097811_33520600'
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:       <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/pages/home.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__2767656240117324842_33999760'
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/helpers/application_helper.rb:14:in `logo'
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (logo.png isn't precompiled):
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:     <a class="brand"><%=link_to logo, root_path %></a>
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     20: 
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     21: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:   <div class="navbar-inner">
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:     <ul class="nav pull-right">
2013-03-01T00:42:22+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=startupblog.herokuapp.com fwd="174.95.207.136" dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=5ms connect=15ms service=25ms status=500 bytes=643



source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'devise'
end


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.3.0.1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
 gem 'mongrel',  '1.2.0.pre2'
 gem 'devise'

end


gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is clearly listed:

```
/app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
```

If you can make your app public, I'll be able to check it right away, but its pretty probably that you didn't commit your Gemfile or Gemfile.lock, make sure you have devise listed on your Gemfile like

```
gem 'devise'
```

Then run

```
bundle
```

And commit both Gemfile and Gemfile.lock into your souce code and push it to heroku

Comment: thanks for your response. Still seem to be getting the same error, i've attached the gemfile to the op.

Comment: That's because your gem 'devise' is within the group 'development' and 'assets'
The group 'assets' is loaded when compiling the js and css
The group 'development' is loaded when you start the server on your desktop
You have to make it globally available for all environments, that means out of any group, check this out:

https://gist.github.com/rorra/5061442

Comment: Make sure you have something like this on config/application.rb: https://gist.github.com/rorra/5061631

Answer (score 1):

Appears the error is:

```
/app/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Devise (NameError)
```

Have you got devise in your Gemfile?

Related: [why do I get uninitialized constant Devise name Error when running webrick server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551946/why-do-i-get-uninitialized-constant-devise-name-error-when-running-webrick-serve)