# Devise Rails 4 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

New Rails app.  Very simple

Followed https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

now getting:

**NameError: uninitialized constant User**

```
   root@youplus:/var/www/html/YouPlus# rake db:migrate --trace
    ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
    ** Invoke environment (first_time)
    ** Execute environment
    rake aborted!
    NameError: uninitialized constant User
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `const_get'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:238:in `block in constantize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `inject'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:236:in `constantize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:301:in `get'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:80:in `to'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:75:in `modules'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:92:in `routes'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:159:in `default_used_route'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/mapping.rb:69:in `initialize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:335:in `new'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise.rb:335:in `add_mapping'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:224:in `block in devise_for'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
    /var/www/html/YouPlus/config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
    /var/www/html/YouPlus/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:71:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
    /var/www/html/YouPlus/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.5/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
    /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
    /usr/local/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

How do I fix this?

Tried
[why do I get uninitialized constant Devise name Error when running webrick server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551946/why-do-i-get-uninitialized-constant-devise-name-error-when-running-webrick-serve)

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1605

Comment: After which command are you getting this error? Some more details in your question will go along way.

Comment: rails g devise:install

Comment: And you have already run, `rails generate devise:install` and `rails generate devise User`?

Comment: rails generate devise USERS

Comment: Needs to be `rails generate devise User`.

Comment: how do i remove USERS

Comment: Depends on how extended your application is? I assume you are just now implementing User class, so i would delete the files generated for that. ie: (model, test model, factory (if FactoryGirl installed)). Then I would delete that migration file. Keep in mind for future though not to delete migration files after they have been migrated. Then you can re-run the proper command. In Rails, keep your models `singular` and when creating through command line, only capitalize the first letter. ie: `User`, `Post`.