# Rails error in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have install devise but getting this error .I have followed all the steps of devise and when i run rake db:migrate it is showing this error
 
`const_get': uninitialized constant View (NameError)

Comment: post the complete log

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551946/why-do-i-get-uninitialized-constant-devise-name-error-when-running-webrick-serve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have added `require 'devise'` in `config/application.rb` file