# Rails 4 in action devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

Again I have a problem.
In chapter 6 Rails 4 in Action I generated Devise views with `rails g devise:views` and it was OK. Then I made some changes in .html files and wanted to run `bundle exec rspec` and got this error:

```
$ bundle exec rspec
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/usr/local/bin/rspec)
NameError: uninitialized constant Devise
  /home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
  /home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
  /home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
  /home/rafal/ruby_workspace/ticketee/spec/controllers/projects_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `load'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1226:in `block in load_spec_files'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `each'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1224:in `load_spec_files'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

Could you help me?

Comment: The answers and comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551946/why-do-i-get-uninitialized-constant-devise-name-error-when-running-webrick-serve should help.

Comment: Is devise in your Gemfile.lock

Comment: I tried everything from that post and it didn't help..
Yes Devise is in my Gemfile.lock

Comment: Do you have this in a repo somewhere?

Comment: Here is my repo: https://github.com/fazowski/Ticketee but i doesn't contain code with this error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that rspec doesn't load devise, to fix it, in your `spec/rails_helper.rb` file add `require devise` after `require 'rspec/rails'`